# Duplicate values when using inner_join()

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

I am trying to use a `t.test()` to compare means for multiple columns in a dataframe where the values to compare are within each column. I have several columns of metadata (`Date`,`Assay`,`Timing`) for each row. My data looks like `df` below where the data collected is not paired and `meas1` and `meas2` are different measured outcomes that are not related. The comparison I am trying to make is between `meas1[Timing=="Start"]` and `meas1[Timing == "End"]` on each date, for each assay, and each test. My actual data has ~10 columns of measurement data which affects my syntax for some of the subsetting.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Date=rep(c("2022-01-01","2022-01-02"), each = 18),
    Assay = rep(c("Gly", "Asp", "Con"), each = 3, times = 4),
    Timing = c(rep("Start",9),rep("End",9)),
    meas1=round(rnorm(36,5,3),0),
    meas2=round(rnorm(36,8,9),0))
```

I have tried a couple of different approaches. One is to attempt to use `inner_join()` and `pivot_longer()` to join the data together using a separate dataframe of the metadata, but I am not getting the desired outcome.

```
comp <- list(Assay = c("Gly","Asp","Con"),
    first = "Start",
    last = "End",
    test = names(df %>% select(-Date,-Assay,-Timing))) %>%
    cross_df()

df_pivot <- df %>%
    pivot_longer(c(-Date,-Assay,-Timing), names_to = "test")

t_tests <- comp %>%
    inner_join(df_pivot, by = c("Assay", "test", "first"="Timing")) %>%
    rename(initial = value) %>%
    inner_join(df_pivot, by = c("Date", "Assay", "test", "last"="Timing")) %>%
    rename(final = value)

t_tests

# A tibble: 108 × 7
   Assay first last  test  Date       initial final
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Gly   Start End   meas1 2022-01-01       8     8
 2 Gly   Start End   meas1 2022-01-01       8     9
 3 Gly   Start End   meas1 2022-01-01       8     4
 4 Gly   Start End   meas1 2022-01-01       4     8
 5 Gly   Start End   meas1 2022-01-01       4     9
 6 Gly   Start End   meas1 2022-01-01       4     4
 7 Gly   Start End   meas1 2022-01-01      -1     8
 8 Gly   Start End   meas1 2022-01-01      -1     9
 9 Gly   Start End   meas1 2022-01-01      -1     4
10 Gly   Start End   meas1 2022-01-02       6     1
# … with 98 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

The initial values are repeated for each distinct final value, which is not what I want since the data aren't paired. I am trying to get only 36 rows: 2 dates, 3 assays, 2 tests, 6 values for each test (3 values by 2 columns). In other words, rows 1:9 should be condensed to 3 rows (row 1, 5, and 9) containing only the unique initial and final values. This is where I need help. The 1,5,9 pattern should repeat but I was hoping to avoid slicing the data after the fact.

Assuming that part was done correctly, I'd proceed as follows, which gives me the summary tibble of `t.test()` outcomes that I want:

```
t_tests <- t_tests %>%
    mutate(first = NULL, last = NULL) %>%
    group_by(Date,Assay,test) %>%
    group_modify(~broom::tidy(t.test(.x$initial,.x$final))) %>% ungroup()

t_tests
# A tibble: 12 × 13
   Date       Assay test    estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic   p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method                  alternative
   <chr>      <chr> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                   <chr>      
 1 2022-01-01 Asp   values1   -2.33       5.67     8        -1.79  0.0989        11.7   -5.18       0.511 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
 2 2022-01-01 Asp   values2    9.33       6.67    -2.67      2.14  0.0643         8.16  -0.698     19.4   Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
 3 2022-01-01 Con   values1    3.67       6.67     3         2.17  0.0552        10.1   -0.0984     7.43  Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
 4 2022-01-01 Con   values2   -8.33       2.67    11        -2.93  0.0110        14.1  -14.4       -2.23  Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
 5 2022-01-01 Gly   values1    0.333      5        4.67      0.343 0.737         13.1   -1.76       2.43  Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
 6 2022-01-01 Gly   values2   -0.333      5.67     6        -0.100 0.922         11.5   -7.63       6.96  Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
 7 2022-01-02 Asp   values1    2          6        4         1.36  0.193         16     -1.12       5.12  Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
 8 2022-01-02 Asp   values2   11         11.7      0.667     2.02  0.0731         9.27  -1.26      23.3   Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
 9 2022-01-02 Con   values1   -2          4.33     6.33     -1.75  0.0999        15.4   -4.43       0.429 Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
10 2022-01-02 Con   values2   11         11.3      0.333     5.64  0.0000761     13.2    6.79      15.2   Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
11 2022-01-02 Gly   values1   -2.33       3        5.33     -4.43  0.000594      13.8   -3.47      -1.20  Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided  
12 2022-01-02 Gly   values2    1          6        5         0.267 0.793         14.5   -7.00       9.00  Welch Two Sample t-test two.sided
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a run_id within each date/assay/timing group so that you can match use that as a join criteria to avoid the duplication.

There's clue, when you say

> I am trying to get only 36 rows: 2 dates, 3 assays, 2 tests, 6 values for each test (3 values by 2 columns)

You have a date column with 2 unique dates, an assay column with 3 unique assays, a test column with 2 unique tests.... you also need a column with the 3 unique values for your "3 values by 2 columns". I'll call the column `run_id`.

I'll also skip the `comp` data frame, and essentially do a self-join:

```
pivot2 = df %>%
  group_by(Date, Assay, Timing) %>%
  mutate(run_id = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("meas"), names_to = "test") 

t_tests = 
  full_join(
    filter(pivot2, Timing == "Start") %>% select(-Timing, initial = value),
    filter(pivot2, Timing == "End") %>% select(-Timing, final = value),
    by = c("Date", "Assay", "run_id", "test")
  )
# # A tibble: 36 × 6
#    Date       Assay run_id test  initial final
#    <chr>      <chr>  <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 2022-01-01 Gly        1 meas1       1    -1
#  2 2022-01-01 Gly        1 meas2       4     7
#  3 2022-01-01 Gly        2 meas1       0     1
#  4 2022-01-01 Gly        2 meas2      10     8
#  5 2022-01-01 Gly        3 meas1       8     5
#  6 2022-01-01 Gly        3 meas2     -16     4
#  7 2022-01-01 Asp        1 meas1       6     7
#  8 2022-01-01 Asp        1 meas2      28    -5
#  9 2022-01-01 Asp        2 meas1       4     6
# 10 2022-01-01 Asp        2 meas2       9     9
# # … with 26 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I use a `full_join` so that even if one data/assay/timing combo has a different number of runs, everything will still be included.

Comment: worked great with a few mods! Thanks a bunch!